# Question of LINQ optimisation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance

If I have the following code, is the compiler instantiating each result or is it wise enough to just count how many corresponding records are in the table? If not, it may force me to use a different strategy on larger queries.

```
from c in context.RendezVous
where c.RepID == repID &&
    c.DateHeureRV != null &&
    c.DateHeureRV.Value.Date == date.Date
select c).Count();
```

Thank you!

Comment: LINQ only executes the code lazily, e.g. only when your are trying to access it element. Every expression before that is just adding to the dynamic expression that is build inside the LINQ query object.

Comment: @Yet: However, in this case, `.Count()` fully evaluates the query immediately...

Comment: @Reed, Ok good to know next time I use it.

Comment: Which kind of LINQ? LINQ to SharePoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of `context`.

If this is an Entity Framework or Linq to SQL query, and `context` is `IQueryable<T>`, then the query gets turned into a SQL query *on the server* which just returns the count as a single integer.

If this is an in-memory collection (ie: `IEnumerable<T>`), each item is iterated in sequence (Linq to Objects) and counted.

I suspect the former is true, since you mentioned "table" and you're not using the LINQ to Dataset extension methods. In that case, you will stay very efficient.

Comment: If the source implements `ICollection<T>` linq-to-objects will just read the `Count` property instead of enumerating it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: No it won't, in this case, because it has to look at the results of the `.Where()` methods, which convert the `ICollection<T>` into an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: (In general, you are right - but that would be more if it was just `context.Count()` without the where clauses)

Comment: Ah yes, I was careless and missed the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

This will execute (more or less):

```
select count(*)
from rendezvous
where repid='...' and dateheurerv is not null and dateheurerv='...'
```

Linq will add no real overhead to the query and the count will be processed server-side.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute a SQL query with the three WHERE conditions you listed and return the count of the matching rows, it will only materialize *the actual count*, not each row - if that was your question.

Comment: Nothing in the original question mentions SQL - this could all be in memory.

Comment: So there will be no performance effect wether the table has 5 or 200 colums ?

Comment: @SethO the words `context` and `table` suggest this is databased backed linq( linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, ...)